# First order vs Second order online machine learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, online-learning

In this [git repo](https://github.com/LIBOL/SOL) the online learning algorithms are classified as first order and second order. I tried searching what it means, yet I'm unable to understand the different between such first oder and second order online learning algorithms.

What is the difference between first order and second order online learning?

Comment: Study the canonical second order optimization algorithm: [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization). Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 3):

First order and second order algorithms are algorithms which use respectively at least first derivative / second derivative.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201384/what-is-the-definition-of-a-first-order-method) explains well the definition.